# JAVA - Can I delete @Autowire directly?

Tags: java, autowired

after my teammates merged her changes (implements @EnableFeignClients for our SpringBootApplication and created some feign clients, properties and configs from the main branch), when boot the application it will pop up the  `The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context from a cycle: xxx`

To resolve this issue I deleted some @Autowired from some involved controller/service classes and make them private and then the application can be boot successfully:

before my change:

```java
@Autowired
MyUtil myUtil; //@Component

@Autowired
MyConfig myConfig; //@Component

@Autowired
MyApi myApi; //Interface class

public void myFunction(){
   String id = myUtil.getId();
   String name = myConfig.getNameById(id);
   myApi.sendInfo(id, name); 
}
```

after  my change:

```java
private MyUtil myUtil; //@Component

private MyConfig myConfig; //@Component

private MyApi myApi; //@Component

public void myFunction(){
   String id = myUtil.getId();
   String name = myConfig.getNameById(id);
   myApi.sendInfo(id, name); 
}
```

Spring version:

```java
<groupID>org.springframework.boot</groupID>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.6.11</version>
```

and here are my concerns:

1. Will there be any impact after my changes (functional, performance, etc.)?
2. In my case (or in most scenarios in the future development),  should i use @Autowired? When need to?  When doesn't need to?

Comment: *"The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context from a cycle:"* - that means that the change has introduced a **cyclic dependency**. In other words, there are two (or more beans) which can't be instantiated because creation of one of the one of them requires an instance of another and vice versa.

Comment: There are two conclusions I could make: **1.** The information you've provided is **incomplete** (the message should contain information which beans formed a cycle) - you have to provide the full message and the second bean. **2.** Cyclic dependency is always caused by the **design fault**, and can be fully resolved by improving the class design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL DR. You cannot delete @Autowired directly.

@Autowired is used by Spring in order to do *dependency injection* ( I know this is a fancy word)

```
@Autowired
ChickenService chickenService
```

@Autowired is *almost* equivalent to ChickenService chickenService = new ChickenService();

After your change,`private MyConfig myConfig; //@Component` **`myConfig`** will be null and therefore you introduced a bug.

Suppose that you have an EggService

```
@Service
public class ChickenService {
  
   @Autowired 
   private EggService eggService;

}
```

The chicken holds a reference to the egg

```
@Service
public class EggService {
  
   @Autowired 
   private ChickenService; 

}
```

Now you have a chicken and egg problem.
https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired help the spring to find where it should inject classes.

The impact is that spring will not create objects of the classes where you removed the annotation.

Additional way to create objects in spring are with setter or constructor injection.

Example of constructor injection will be something like:

```
public YourClassName(MyUtil myUtil, MyConfig myConfig, MyApi myApi){
      this.myUtil = myUtil;   
      this.myConfig = myConfig;   
      this.myApi = myApi;   
}
```

I think also good idea as well to check why @Autowired not working. Can you provide full error? Does your class annotated with @Service or something

Comment: Thanks for your response, the dependency circle error we've resolved by re-design the project structure